# Using Python to add/remove Ubuntu login script items

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, login-script

I have written a Python application and would like to give my users the option of having the app automatically launch itself when the user logs in. It is important that the user is able to toggle this option on/off from within the app itself, rather than having to manually edit login scripts, so this needs to be done from within the Python code rather than from a shell script. The app is deployed on Ubuntu Linux, any suggestions for the best way of doing this?

Comment: Any problem with using the built in autostart functionality in ubuntu?
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=565376

Comment: I shiver just thinking someone develops application for ONE linux distribution. If it's not Ubuntu-specific, please make the time to actually make it usable on other distributions too. I am pretty sure if you ask at their -devel mailing list(s) they will gladly help you with specifics...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html)'s what you need to handle autostart.

Comment: For future reference - I ended up writing a small shell script to do this using the information from your link, and invoking it from Python via popen().